# How to deal with numerical variables with missing value when doing Logistic Regression in Python?

Tags: python, logistic-regression, missing-data

I'm building a credit score model and some numerical attributes like age of most recent inquiry have missing value. They are missing because these people didn't have an inquiry before so this attribute is not applicable for them.

I do want to include this attribute in the model. Here's the dilemma: if I keep this attribute numerical, those clients with missing value would be excluded but I want them to be considered in the model. If I bin this attribute, those different levels would be treated as categories and I wouldn't be able to keep the monotonicity of age.

1. Is there a way to keep null records for a numerical variable when doing logistic regression in Python? Missing data imputation is not applicable in this case since these data should be kept as null.
2. If I use bins, is it possible to keep the monotonicity between bins? For example, age of most recent inquiry in bin of >12 should cause more severe effect on credit score rather than in bin of [1,2].
3. I use One Hot Encoding when binning. How can I treat all the levels of a variable as a group and decide its importance rather than treating all the levels as independent predictors?

Comment: Either drop or impute. Null values don't fly in regression. Just look at its math. I don't understand your bins and monotonicity of age. Can you clarify?

Comment: Yes - I change the numerical variables into categorical ones to keep the null records included. Say the **age of most recent inquiry** varies from 0 to 30 and there are null records. I bin it as 0-6, 6-12, 13+ and null records as undefined. In this way a client with age of most recent inquiry to be 5 falls into the category of 0-6, hence bin of 0-6 has value 1 and all other bins have value 0. Then I put all the bins/dummy variables into the model rather than the original numerical variable.

Comment: But in this way, we can't ensure that when age increases the output variable would go up/down. So is there any way to keep this kind of monotonicity? thx!

Comment: Here is your imputation strategy: If 0-6 then avg bad rate of 0-6. If 6-12 then avg bad rate of 6-12. If 13+ then avg bad rate of 13+. If null then avg bad rate of null. This way instead of dummies you get a continuous variable of bad rates, such as .43, .89, .25 etc. Your binned variable is continuous after the transformation, bins are numberified perfectly, you can measure the significance of your variable nicely, Sun is shining, wind is blowing mildly, and everybody is happy - including you, your data and your boss :)

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that's a good way of imputation, thank you! But the null ones still can't be put into the model right?

Comment: They can! If you just impute them with their bad rates that you observed in your training sample, all nulls become that number. Of course, you can't feed them into the model as is, i.e. keeping them as null.